# Package Manager Console Error

Tags: model-view-controller, powershell, windows-7, nuget, visual-studio-express

When I start visual studio express 2012 for web I get this error in the package manager console.

> Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Core because of the following
>   error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information.
>   Loader Exceptions:
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I don't remember adding anything new to visual studio. I searched other related problems but they don't work for me.

I tried repairing visual studio. I also tried re-installing visual studio which temporarily removed the problem but it is back again.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Check any profile scripts that might be getting loaded.  Check C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1, C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1, C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\NuGet_profile.ps1 and C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1.

Comment: There may actually be not enough memory ...

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I checked my memory I still have a lot.

Comment: @KeithHill Thank you I'll check. If they are loaded what does that imply?

Comment: @KeithHill None of them are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. I suspected it is something from windows update that messed up with my VS since I didn't really add anything to VS. I am not sure which updates to remove so I just uninstalled all the windows update that starts in a certain date. Here are the actual steps that I did:

What I did is uninstalled visual studio 2012 express for web following this [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441?wa=wsignin1.0).

And then uninstalled windows updates starting from the date I believe the error started appearing.

After I used CCleaner to clean my registry. Had to run it 2 times to just to make sure it is clean. I'm not sure if this actually helps. I just heard from my friend that uninstalling applications sometime leaves registry keys behind.

Finally, I installed visual studio again. Package manager is back to normal.

Restarted my laptop and it is still working. So I guess it is solved.

I think System Restore would do solve this instead of doing all this steps. But system restore was not an option for .